# Transformation parameters for Everest_Bangladesh and Nepal_Nagarkot to WGS84

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, nepal, bangladesh

What are the parameters for transformation of Everest_Bangladesh and Nepal_Nagarkot Geographical Coordinate System datums to WGS84 datum?

Answer (score 1):

Nepal_Nagarkot is Nepal 1981

Transformation to wgs84 is

Nepal 1981 to WGS 84 (1)

https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::6208

```
X-axis translation 293.17 metre
Y-axis translation 726.18 metre
Z-axis translation 245.36 metre

COORDINATEOPERATION["Nepal 1981 to WGS 84 (1)",
  SOURCECRS[
    GEODCRS["Nepal 1981",
      DATUM["Nepal 1981",
        ELLIPSOID["Everest 1830 (1937 Adjustment)",6377276.345,300.8017,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
      CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
      ID["EPSG",6207]]],
  TARGETCRS[
    GEODCRS["WGS 84",
      DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
      CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
      ID["EPSG",4326]]],
  METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9603]],
  PARAMETER["X-axis translation",293.17,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",726.18,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",245.36,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  ID["EPSG",6208]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Everest_Bangladesh is Kalianpur 1937

Transformation to wgs84 is

Kalianpur 1937 to WGS 84 (1)

https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::1155

```
X-axis translation 282 metre
Y-axis translation 726 metre
Z-axis translation 254 metre

COORDINATEOPERATION["Kalianpur 1937 to WGS 84 (1)",
  SOURCECRS[
    GEODCRS["Kalianpur 1937",
      DATUM["Kalianpur 1937",
        ELLIPSOID["Everest 1830 (1937 Adjustment)",6377276.345,300.8017,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
      CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
      ID["EPSG",4144]]],
  TARGETCRS[
    GEODCRS["WGS 84",
      DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
      CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
      ID["EPSG",4326]]],
  METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9603]],
  PARAMETER["X-axis translation",282,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",726,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",254,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
  ID["EPSG",1155]]
```